# Removing browser ICON from home screen

Tags: settings, browser, hardware, uninstallation

Is there a way to remove the browser ICON from my home page?

Comment: What is your device model? Android version? Are you using 3rd-party homescreen? Usually you just need to hold and drag the icon to "trash bin".

Comment: it's an android. The browser I want to remove is the one that came with the phone (a tracfone setup) Just dragging the browder icon to the trash bin doesn't work

Comment: @AndrewT., what you suggested will uninstall the app if it is not a system app. From the OP's comment, it appears that this is indeed a system app, and so to remove the icon on a stock launcher, it would need to be held down and dragged to the `X` icon, labelled "Remove".

Answer (score 1):

Going by the OP's comment, I'll just leave my comment as an answer.

Dragging the app icon to the "trash bin" will uninstall the app if it is not a system app. From the OP's comment, it appears that this is indeed a system app, and so to remove the icon on stock (AOSP or most custom, e.g. Not MIUI or ZenUI) launchers, it would need to be held down and dragged to the `X` icon, labelled "Remove".